# how to make a selection?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

please help make a selection. somewhere in the middle of the html-pages have the following code:

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="single-stone"></table>
<table width="100%"></table>
<br>
<div style="padding:0px 10px; text-align:left;
margin-top:-20px;
">
    <br>
    <div>
        <strong>Гранит Мансуровский     </strong> продается в готовых изделиях, а также слэбах.
        Сейчас <strong>Мансуровский</strong> есть в наличии на складе
    </div>
    <br>

    <p></p><h2>Название</h2>Мансуровский.<p></p><p></p><h2>Цвет</h2>Однородный серо-зеленый цвет с редкими темно-серыми или черными включениями (жилы и пятна), часто предлагают как белый гранит, т.к. он является самым светлым из гранитов РФиСНГ.<p></p><p></p><h2>Месторождение</h2>Урал<p></p><p></p><h2>Зернистость/Структура</h2>Мелкозернистый,вструктуре присутствует магний.<p></p><p></p><h2>Особенности</h2><!--Принеправильноммо нтажеилиприконтактесводойначинаетсяестественнаяреакция- ржавление.Соблюдаявсеусловиямонтажа,ипользуясьуслугамипрофессионалов,можноизбежатьнежелательнойкоррозии.--> Один из самых популярных камней в России,его любят за однородность цвета,доступность и в наличии, и в цене.<p></p><p> </p><h2>Сфера применения</h2>Широко используется в дорожном строительстве(бордюры,брусчатка),для мощения площадей,набережных,метро. <p></p><p></p><h2>Условия доставки/Сроки</h2>Всегда есть в наличии в необработанном и термообработанном виде, минимальные сроки на любые изделия из данного камня.<p></p><h2>Физико-механические характеристики гранита Мансуровский</h2><table width="50%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"><tbody><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>объемный вес,кг/м3</td><td>2710</td></tr><tr><td>водопоглощение,%</td><td>0,48</td></tr><tr><td>класс радиоактивности</td><td>1 класс</td></tr><tr><td>истираемость,г/см2</td><td>0,40</td></tr><tr><td>морозостойкость,циклов</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>предел прочности при сжатии,кг/см2(МПа)</td><td>169</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

out of it you need to get the text:

```
<strong>Гранит Мансуровский     </strong> продается в готовых изделиях, а также слэбах.
Сейчас <strong>Мансуровский</strong> есть в наличии на складе
```

while strong tags can not be.

here is my failed attempt:

```
    description = doc.xpath('//table[@id="single-stone"]/following-sibling::div/div/@content')
    print(description)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "while strong tags can not be"?

Comment: they may or may not be in this html-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an XPath-only solution, you could pick off all the pieces of text in the `div` tag using `//text()`:

```
import lxml.html as LH
doc = LH.parse('data', parser=LH.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
for elt in doc.xpath(
    '//table[@id="single-stone"]/following-sibling::div/div//text()'):
    print(elt)
```

yields

```
Гранит Мансуровский     
 продается в готовых изделиях, а также слэбах.
        Сейчас 
Мансуровский
 есть в наличии на складе
```

Or, you could call the `text_content` method of the `div` element to obtain all
the text:

```
for elt in doc.xpath('//table[@id="single-stone"]/following-sibling::div/div'):
    print(elt.text_content())
```

yields

```
        Гранит Мансуровский      продается в готовых изделиях, а также слэбах.
        Сейчас Мансуровский есть в наличии на складе
```